# Best Practice For Displaying Facebook Profile Pictures In an Android App

Tags: android, facebook, imageview, profile, image

I want to have an android app that displays users' facebook profile pictures. I'm wondering what the bast practice is for this purpose. Should I make ImageView load pictures at runtime from facebook URI? or save the pictures to my own server and send them to the devices in bytes on demand? or cache them locally?
What is the "common" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would cache them locally unless you intend to have hundreds of them.
It would make the app work offline and display the images a lot faster.

You would have to update them regularly though as a user's Facebook profile picture can change fairly often.

Comment: I don't have a static set of users. I can probably cache the pictures when they get displayed, but it's still a question how to fetch the pictures on demand as new users need to be displayed. What's in my mind is apps like twitter or facebook app itself. How do they solve the problem? I see they don't take too much time to load the pictures.

Comment: In that case have a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html